# Find a substring in NSMutableArray of string fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, string-comparison

I have an array like

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"How many degrees ", @"Which club degree", @"body building", nil];
```

A want to filter only those string contains degree. I am using old IOS, i don't have `[string stringcontains]` method

The required Array must have -> 1. How many degrees  2. Which club degree

**First Method I use**

```
NSString *strToMatch=@"degree";

    for (NSString *description in arr)
    {
     NSComparisonResult result = [description compare:strToMatch options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [strToMatch length])];

           if (result == NSOrderedSame)
              {
                 // statement to run on comparison succeeded..
              }
    }
```

**Second Method**

```
for (NSString *description in arr)
   {

      if ([description rangeOfString:strToMatch options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"I am matched....");
        }
  }
```

It is working fine. I have shown you the code to compare a single string but i have to compare this array with another array of string. I want to speed up my code. Is there any other better approach to find it.

And how can we create a NSPredicate to compare two array of string. Find first arrray of string as a substring in second array.

And which approach is fast.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` and `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` as it's available from iOS 3.0

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"How many degrees ", @"Which club degree", @"body building", nil];
NSString *searchText = @"degree";
NSArray *filtered = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains %@", searchText]];
```

Also for case-insensitive and diacritic-insensitive search use

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"How many degrees ", @"Which club degree", @"body building", nil];
NSString *searchText = @"deGree";
NSArray *filtered = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@", searchText]];
```

If you want to search array of keywords in another array, you can use `NSCompoundPredicate` which is also available from iOS 3.0.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"How many degrees ", @"Which club degree", @"body building", @"hello world" , nil];
NSArray *keywordsToSearch = @[@"deGree", @"world"];
NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *keyword in keywordsToSearch) {
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@", keyword]];
}
NSPredicate *wholePredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

NSArray *filtered = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:wholePredicate];
```

Also you can check performance and choose the best one.

```
NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
// .... here searching code
NSTimeInterval endTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"Duration %f", endTime - startTime);
```

Comment: running perfectly but tell me which method is fast and when to chose between NSPredicate or my way..

Comment: I think Apple's implementation should be faster, but anyway I have added performance code, check me edit.

Comment: Thanks,I am new to IOS, can you suggest me some sites or tutorial through which i can enhance my concepts about IOS. Not code.I want to learn concepts .

Comment: I think WWDC videos can be very helpful (especially 'Advanced' videos) https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ also you can check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/